# "Switching users" in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I am using a computer previously used by someone else. I logged in to Lotus Notes under my .nsf file, but I'm getting many errors. It seems Notes is trying to access the previous user's data still, in many different places. The Mail button on the home page tries to go to the previous user's inbox, and some settings are inaccessible.

What can I do to make a clean break from the previous user's settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lotus Notes uses the concept of location documents to control some user settings such as the location of the mail file. The name of the current location document is shown in the lower right corner and is usually called something like Office, Network, Online etc. You can click the location name and then edit it.

In the location document you need to go to the Mail tab and change the location of the mail file to match the location of your mail file.

This most likely fixes most of your problems.

For reference: the following help document contains information on location documents: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Locations_and_accounts_LN853

Comment: Never noticed that sneaky little spot for all the good settings. This not only fixed my current problem, but would have fixed several previous problems I've had with Notes. Thanks.

Comment: Do you not have a Notes administrator that configures that stuff for you?  I know we run an agent that does that kind of stuff for people when we switch their PCs around. If you update locations, and some settings are still off, you can also delete the bookmarks.nsf and itll reset most of the toolbars and bookmarks.